# How can I define longtable to textsize

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, textwidth

I have a long table that would run over 3 pages. 
I can either run the table over multiple pages using

```
\begin{longtable}
.........
\end{longtable}
```

but it is not defined within the widthof the page and thus runs out on the sides.

I tried defining the width of my table with multiple options such as:

```
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%   \begin{tabular}{lll}
or  
%\footnotesize
%\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}p{8cm}p{5cm}} 
or 
%\setlength\LTleft{-30pt}

%\setlength\LTright{30pt}
```

they all work on defining my width fine but the table does not run over multiple pages it runs out of the first page and disappears.

So I can either run the long table option or the normal table with tabular specifics but none give me a complete table.

I cannot divide the table into multiple ones.

Comment: Probably `xltabular` does what you want (combine `longtable` and `tabularx`)

Comment: You can also use p type columns in a longtable. Regarding resizebox: do not use resizebox to make a table fit into the textwidth as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: First, worry about making the table narrow enough by reducing the font size (\small, \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \tiny IIRC).  You can also reduce \tabcolsep.